# android - any way to tweak the proximity sensor?

Tags: android, listener, distance, android-sensors, proximity

i would like to tweak the listener's event that i get from the proximity sensor , so that it would notify me if the user is X centimeters (even 10 centimeters) from the device . maybe even get the exact value for each time.

for some reason , i get notified that the user is close to the device at different distance on each device .

is such a thing possible? are there any workarounds ? it seems that the proximity sensor almost doesn't have any tutorials and information.